# WebApi access Exchange mailbox folder Calendar,Notes,Tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need create a procedure for rename some folder on user mailbox in Office365.
I have used Microsft Graph API but I'm not able to find folder who are not "mail folder". In Exchange you can create other type of folder (Contact,Tasks,Notes).

There is a API who can manage this kind of folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple folder types supported:

- [Mail Folder](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailfolder)
- [Contact Folder](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contactfolder)
- [Tasks Folder (beta)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktaskfolder)
- [Calendar Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendargroup)

Outlook Notes are not supported by Microsoft Graph.